# how share some values between all instances of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to store some values (settings) that are shared amongst all instances of a model. What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: these values need to be editable through forms, so hardcoding won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: To me it sounds like this shared info should be in another model.

Comment: The only problem is that this other model would have only a single row in the database. It would work, but i'm hoping there's a better solution.

Comment: There's really no downside to having a table with only one row.  You're persisting all of your other data in the database, and this belongs in the database too.  If you anticipate needing something like this for other models, you could setup a `Configuration` model (or some better domain-specific name) and store the shared settings for multiple models in one table.

Comment: please make your comment an answer and i will select it, thanks